# Renting a car in Costa Rica with Annual Car Hire Excess Insurance from the UK

Tags: car-rentals, insurance, costa-rica

I get that in Costa Rica you need to purchase the Liability Protection, but I'm wondering if I can waive/not buy Car Protection (as it's called on the adobe car rental website) by purchasing Annual Car Hire Excess Insurance from the UK?  The Abode website says that Car Protection is:

> Waiver of financial responsibility in case of damages to the rental car, produced by a car accident, collision or roll over, total or partial theft with a deductible (excess) of US$1,000. Does not cover vandalism damages, cost of tow truck and road assistance. To decline, you must present written proof of coverage from your credit card issuer. Efective October 1st 2021, VISA will stop providing its cardholders with Gold and Platinum cards, the benefit of vehicle damage coverage for rental cars in Costa Rica. For more information click here.

As this seemed to be something offered once by credit card companies, it does seem logical that 3rd party insurance is something that I can purchase to waive this fee.

My UK insurer explains that Annual Car Hire Excess insurance is:

> If you hire a car and it’s damaged or stolen, car hire excess insurance covers you for the excess costs you have to pay the rental company.
> The excess amount you’re liable to pay depends on the company you hire from, but it’s normally between £500 to £2,000.

Are both of these products the same but slightly differently worded.  I do know Costa Rica has slightly different insurance needs than a lot of other countries.

Comment: Apologies if I'm missing something but excess insurance only covers the excess on an insurance policy. You probably need to get 3rd party/liability insurance and insurance for fire/theft/accident, and then excess insurance will cover your excess if you need to claim for 3rd party, fire, theft, or accident on one of the other policies. Normally there is no requirement to get excess cover when you hire a car.

Comment: @StuartF you might be right, so the Abode insurance is actually insurance that will make my excess no more than $1000 for the conditions listed and then the UK insurer will pay the excess that I paid.

Comment: Insurance terms are notoriously complicated and have pages and pages of "weasel language" in their terms and conditions. Without plowing through these terms in great detail, it will be difficult to come up with a confident answer.

Comment: What did your UK insurer say when you asked them?